# Solr Sorting by relevancy

Tags: solr

I can't get my head around Solr Sorting by certain fields, 
Let's say i have such set of documents :

```
 {"id": 126,
 "post": "Hello, welcomes you :)",
 "date": "2011-08-12T18:52:36Z",
 "user": "Ahmed",
 "user_photo": "t_4944949.jpeg",
 "likes": 1,
 "comments": 0}
```

I just want to sort it by sum(likes, comment) with priority of ^2 and by date with priority of ^1

what is the sentax to write that ?
Note: `q=*:*`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax:

```
sort=<field name>+<direction>[,<field name>+<direction>]
```

So you will need:

```
sort=date desc, sum(likes, comment) desc
```

the order of sorting is the listing order, look at the example in here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort

```
inStock desc, price asc    //sort by "inStock" descending, then "price" ascending
```

Comment: but which one have more priority than others, let's say i'll be adding more fields to sort

Comment: it goes in order of listing, so date come first in this case. If you reverse the terms it change the priority

Comment: I added the priority explanation to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to give your documents a score of

```
2 * (likes + comments) + recency_score
```

(where `recency_score` depends on the `date`) and sort your results by this score.

You should look into [function query](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery) for this.

The `recency_score` depends on your needs. See this [Solr FAQ](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_boost_the_score_of_newer_documents) for how to boost documents by recency.

For example, you may want to give a score of 1.0 for documents published right now and a score of (1/2) for docs published last year, (1/3) for docs published two years ago and so on. The following query will do this for you:

```
q={!func}sum(product(2,sum(likes,comment)),recip(ms(NOW,date),3.16e-11,1,1))
```

where 3.16e-11 is just 1/(number of milli secs in one year).

Comment: That's exactly what i mean, leme check it and get back to you